# How to create a pointor variable to complete array (not the first element example: int *ptr = &arr, not int *ptr = arr)

Tags: c

I wanted to use the fact that `&arr` points to the complete `arr` and not just the first element, to calculate array length like this

```
int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr ;
```

Now this will work in main function but I want to calculate the size within a function in which array is not defined and takes `arr` as parameter.

As `arr` decays into a pointer when passed into a function. `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` method does not work as it means

```
sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int) 
// i.e. 4/4 = 1.
```

I wanted to use `&arr` method inside a function but that does not work too for some reason... which is why I wanted to pass `&arr` as a parameter inside the function. I tried simply pass it by writing `&arr` as a parameter, but I am confused what is the data type of `&arr` as it says expected.

```
expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[4]'
```

which is good as I am passing `int(*)[4]` only but how to specify this inside function parameter?

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about their differences.

Comment: The first version (which invokes undefined behavior) does not work in functions for the same reason as why the second version does not work in functions. It is just a pointer in the function, it does not have any size information anymore, `&arr + 1` does not make sense for a pointer.

Comment: yes thats why i am tring to pass &arr only now

Comment: Then your function expects a `int (*)[size]` instead of a `int *`. So, the function syntax needs the size. Why don't you want to pass the array and the size?

Comment: `int(*ptr)[4] = &arr;`

Comment: In C, to pass in an array by pointer (which is standard practice), you'll also need to pass in the size of the array (which is also standard practice), or have some other mechanism to determine the end of an array, like a sentinel value (such as `'\0'` in a C string -- which is standard practice for C strings, but rather an infrequent technique for other arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax to pass reference to array in C++ is:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t size(const T (&a)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

for C, you don't have template to deduce size, so type/size would be hard coded:

```
void foo(const int (*arr)[42])
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: so basically i have to indirectly pass the size only

Comment: The C++ tag has been removed in the meantime, to this answer is now pointless.

Answer (score 2):

> ...  to calculate the size within a function in which array is not defined and takes arr as parameter.

In C, when *variable length arrays* are available:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// The array is not defined here.
//                            v
void bar(size_t n, int (*arg)[n]) {
  // Size of the array from main() is calculated here.
  size_t size = sizeof *arg / sizeof *arg[0];
  printf("%p %zu\n", (void*) arg, size);
  // Akin to OP's calculation method
  ptrdiff_t diff = *(arg + 1) - *arg;
  printf("%p %td\n", (void*) arg, diff);
  printf("%p %zu\n", (void*) arg, n);
}

int main(void) {
  // Array defined here.
  int arr[42];
  int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr ;
  printf("Main: %d\n", size);
  size_t sz = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
  bar(sz, &arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Main: 42
0xffffcb40 42
0xffffcb40 42
0xffffcb40 42
```

Comment: Good answer but I'd remove the `int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr ;` since it's just pointless obfuscation. `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` is the correct code, period.

Comment: its technically a unique way of passing size inside array though :)

Comment: @Lundin I included the `int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr ;` to match  OP's "will work in main function" to take OP from known to unknown is steps.